# Must the product of a nil ideal with a minimal right ideal be 0?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, nilpotence

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily with identity or commutative). Suppose that $K$ is a a nil ideal, and let $M$ be a minimal right ideal of $R$. Must it then follow that $MK = 0$?

As $M$ is minimal we must have either $MK = 0$ or $MK = M$, but I can't see any reason why this second case cannot occur. If it did we must necessarily have that $K \supset M$, as $MK \subset M$, $MK \subset K$, so $MK \subset M \cap K \subset M$. So $M$ is nil too. But I can't see how to go from here. I also can't find a counterexample.

The context in which I need this uses this to conclude that $l(K) \neq 0$ (the left annihilator). Even if what I wrote above is false, does this still hold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to ask: are you *sure* you have to even bother considering the case without identity? It is exceedingly rare to ask a question like this in the absence of identity. And it makes it a lot harder. The answer using identity is relatively simple.

Comment: @rschwieb I agree it's pretty horrible, but in my course we don't assume the identity, instead we prove that it must exist under assumptions such as semiprime and DCC on right ideals. In this case it is important that the identity is *not* assumed. In fact I think it is only assumed that $A$ is a *right* nil ideal

Comment: @rschwieb semi-amusingly our lecturer left this as an easy exercise...

Comment: You need something like a Nakayama Lemma for rings without identity.  Maybe it is simpler since $M$ is cyclic, but then again even cyclic modules over rings without identity are more complicated.  Maybe if you check the steps to prove Nakayama it works out: I’ve never actually internalized that proof.  It is true, however, that $K$ is in the Jacobson radical, even without identity.  The thing is that I don’t know if it annihilates minimal right ideals necessarily, without identity.  Maybe you proved that? Because that’s why it’s easy with identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking around, I have the following elementary solution.

Suppose that $MK = M$. Then for some $m \in M$, $mK \neq 0$, and being a right ideal must then be equal to $M$ as $M$ is minimal. But then for some $k \in K$, $mk = m$. $K$ being nil means that $k^n = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But then $m = mk = mk^2 = ... = mk^n = 0$, and $mK = 0$. Thus we must have that $MK = 0$.

Comment: +1 Ah yes, even though $mK$ doesn't necessarily contain $m$, it's still a right submodule, so you don't have to worry about the usual ring-without-identity problem.  So you get $m\in mK$ anyway!  I should have noticed that... well done. and thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The argument is very reminiscent of the way one proves that nilpotent ideals annihilate simple modules, and nilpotent elements of a commutative ring annihilate simple modules.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Dorroh extension allows you to lasso this problem into the realm of rings with identity to solve, after all.

The Dorroh extension of $R$, if you don't already know, is the ring $R^1=\mathbb Z\times R$ with pointwise addition and multiplication given by $(n, a)(m,b)=(nm, nb+ma+ab)$.  It is easy to check that a right ideal of $R$ is a right ideal of $R^1$, and so on with left ideals and ideals.

Also importantly, $K$ remains a nil ideal in $R^1$. It's a basic fact (an easy exercise) to show that $K$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R^1$.

The last question is whether or not $M$ remains simple as an $R^1$ module. In principle, it could have picked up submodules since $R^1$ is bigger than $R$. Now since it is simple as a right $R$ module, given any nonzero $x,y\in M$, there exists $r\in R$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $xn+xr=y$ (this says that every nonzero element of $M$ generates $M$, equivalent to simplicity.)

But if you check the multiplication rules, $(n, r)(0,x)=(0,y)$, so it turns out elements of $M$ generate $M$ with $R^1$ just like they do with $R$, so it is minimal as a right $R^1$ ideal too.

A basic characterization of the Jacobson radical is that it annihilates simple modules, so we'd have that $MK=\{0\}$.

---

This could perhaps be significantly reduced if you had a proof on hand that the Jacobson radical in a ring without identity always annihilates minimal right ideals. I'm simply not positive about this fact, since the situation is a little more complicated than in rings with identity. The only thing I'm pretty sure about is that a nil ideal is still contained in the Jacobson radical of a ring without identity.

Another useful thing would be a Nakayama lemma for rings without identity, which I'm not sure is available and I couldn't find in the sea of references to the ordinary Nakayama lemma.  If such a lemma exists, it would look like $MK=M \implies M=\{0\}$, eliminating the case for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turns out that this can be seen more simply - I've added how as an answer below.

Comment: Yes, that's an improvement! Although I was pretty happy to dicover minimal ideals were preserved in the Dorroh extension...

Comment: And I've learnt about Dorroh extensions so it was still useful!